# How to Pass Active Choices Reactive Parameters to Scriptler

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I have used one ACP( by selecting one value from dropdown) and the value should be passed on to the immediate ACRP scriptler but its not doing this.

my usecase is :

1. a dropdown --- > select one value
2. pass this selected value to scripler in the immediate ACRP so that it will generate values in dropdown and select one from this
3. Should pass to another ACRP scriptler...  and so on for 3 more times.

i was unable to get the parameter in scriptler.

Appreciate your help and if need more info 'll provide iff the above is not sufficient.

Comment: I am looking for this as well, just a sample.  Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm doing a flow like that

1. ACP using scriptler (returning branches of a repo), you can also do it with a Choice parameter or with ACP using groovy script

[image]

- the important thing to have into account if you are using ACP with
  scriptler or groovy is that you should return an arrayList
- the parameters that you pass should be define in the parameter of the scriptler script

2. ACRP using scriptler and referenced to the previous parameter (list the jenkinsfiles in a repo)

[image]

- the parameters that you pass should be define in the parameter of the scriptler script
- notice the Referenced Parameters (deployConfigGifRef)